# How to handle multiple subdomains separately in a Spring MVC app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, subdomain

Supposing I have two subdomains:

Products:

```
products.example.com
```

Users:

```
users.example.com
```

How do I set up a single Spring MVC app to handle each of these domains differently (in my case I want to use a different database depending on which subdomain the user arrives from)?

Answer (score 3):

If the same applications is to be used with the multiple subdomains, then you can make an interceptor (implement `HandlerInterceptor`) that is invoked for every request and store the subdomain in a `ThreadLocal`. Then, based on that value, you can differentiate your actions.